# Using namespaces in TypeScript, but only for types => anti-pattern?

Tags: typescript

From time to time folks tell you that you should not use namespaces in TypeScript.
For example here: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-namespace/ (eslint error: "ES2015 module syntax is preferred over namespaces")

Of course I know what an ES module is and of course my TS code is essentially structured in ES modules.

Nevertheless in certain cases (UI components, complex events etc.) I use namespaces to bundle types (only types!), to make it easier to import and use those types later.
See the following example (this is some kind of UI component). The important thing is that later by using `import { Button } from 'xyz'` you have access to the function `Button` itself and all the types `Button.Type`, `Button.Variant` and `Button.Size` which I consider extremely handy.

```js
export { Button };

namespace Button {
  export type Type = 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset';
  export type Variant = 'default' | 'primary' | 'warning' | 'danger';
  export type Size = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
}

function Button(props: {
  type?: Button.Type;
  variant?: Button.Variant;
  size?: Button.Size;
  // ... and others ...
}) {
  // not important
}
```

[Edit: Please consider this example as a part of a widget library, not an application]

Do you consider this an anti-pattern? Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `Namespace` is considered outdated. It's best to avoid it. Instead do something like:

button.ts

```
export type Type = 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset';
export type Variant = 'default' | 'primary' | 'warning' | 'danger';
export type Size = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
```

app.ts

```
import * as Button from './button'

function createButton(props: {
    type?: Button.Type;
    variant?: Button.Variant;
    size?: Button.Size;
  }) {
    // do something here
}
```

As for why it's outdated or discouraged, well, for one thing, it can cause conflicts and unintentional overlaying of two namespaces. The pattern above puts you in the driver's seat when you import it.

Comment: TYVM for your answer. Could you please do me a favor and explain how "unintentional overlaying of two namespaces" shall be possible? Please be aware that I ALWAYS define the namespace in question in one single file and I ALWAYS export this namespace (like in the example above) and the namespace is never declared global.

Comment: Well, you say that you always do it exactly once... until one day you make a mistake. Or some other library you use could potentially use it. It's easy to screw up and have unexpected behavior or two merged namespaces that weren't intended to be.

Comment: In short, they're just not really necessary anymore.

Comment: Thanks again for your kind help. Regarding your comment "It's easy to screw up": This is exactly my open question: How is it possible to screw things up AFTER `Button` is defined as described above? I just do not know what someone who uses `Button` (in a different file or project) has to do to screw things up?
Also, saying "they`re not really necessary anymore" does not say anything abut whether this is an anti-pattern or not. There are are lot of features in TS that are strictly speking "not really necessary", but still very convenient.

Comment: If I use `export namespace XYZ { ...something... }` in one file and I use `export namespace XYZ { ...something else.... }` in another file than I have two completely different namespaces which just happens to have the same exported name and will never be merged with each other. Am I wrong?

Comment: "Namespace is considered outdated" — who says that? The [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) say nothing about that.

Comment: @Natasha I'm in the same boat - I understand the downsides of using namespace for code, but it's very useful to group types together (as your example clearly stated). Arguments against it are usually "because it's outdated", but I haven't found an objective argument against it. It's been over a year and I'm curious to hear if you continued or stopped using namespaces for types, and why?

Comment: @Joey Actually, I'm still using namespaces for types, but we are are a very small team so  it's not THAT hard to convice the rest of the team that doing this is fine.